# Google analytics event tracking failing to feedback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, query-string

In the following code I am attempting to:-

- Define google analytics on the page
- Add a jquery click event if the page has a certain query string and characters in the domain
- The click event invokes a google analytics tracking event
- I also have code checking for query strings and values within a domain

What is not working:-

- The third item, which is invoking google analytics tracking event, I seem to be hitting it but nothing is being returned into my GA account.

What I have tried:-

- I have triple checked that information for `_gaq_.push` is correctly linking to correct account.
- Used firebug and IE9 developer tools to follow javascript and analyze what is going on. This is how I know I am hitting the event tracking when my scenarios are true.
- Tried in a isolated environment like jsfiddle, will not give link to its because I can't actually give company information out. It doesn't work in js fiddle. ( mainly because jsfiddle can't authenticate with my ga account (domains are different).
- I have tried in an isolated file within my relevant domain still no luck.

  ```
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'mydomain.co.uk']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_setSiteSpeedSampleRate', 100]); // this is a new line, allowing us to see how fast all pages load
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']); // we’ve moved this line down, as ‘setdomain’ (etc) should appear before it

  (function () {
      var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

  $(document).ready(function () {
      var querystring = (function (a) {
          if (a == "") return {};
          var b = {};
          for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
              var p = a[i].split('=');
              if (p.length != 2) continue;
              b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
          }
          return b;
      })(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'));
      if (querystring["utm_expid"] != null) {
          $('a').click(function () {
              if ($(this).attr("href") != 'undefined' && $(this).attr("href") != null) {
                  if ($(this).attr("href").toLowerCase().indexOf("keyword") >= 0 && $(this).attr("href").toLowerCase().indexOf("keyword2") >= 0) {
                      _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'eventCategories', 'eventAction', 'eventLabel']);
                  } else if (($(this).attr("href").toLowerCase().indexOf("keyword") >= 0 && $(this).attr("href").toLowerCase().indexOf("keyword2") >= 0 && $(this).attr("href").toLowerCase().indexOf("keyword3") >= 0) || ($(this).attr("href").toLowerCase().indexOf("keyword4") >= 0)) {
                      _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'eventCategories', 'eventAction', 'eventLabel']);
                  }
              }
          });
      }
  });
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Analytics `_trackEvent` (and `_trackPageview`, etc) work by making a tracking pixel request from the analytics server. If the click results in loading a new page to the same window before the tracking request has completed, you can end up with missing data, or only tracking some of the data.

The following code adds a slight delay before following the link:

```
var delayLink = function(e, url) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setTimeout(function(){location.href = url}, 150);
};

if (querystring["utm_expid"] != null) {
    $('a').click(function (e) {
        if ($(this).attr("href") != 'undefined' && $(this).attr("href") != null) {
            if ($(this).attr("href").toLowerCase().indexOf("keyword") >= 0 && $(this).attr("href").toLowerCase().indexOf("keyword2") >= 0) {
                _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'eventCategories', 'eventAction', 'eventLabel']);
                if (this.target != '_blank') delayLink(e, this.href);
            } else if (($(this).attr("href").toLowerCase().indexOf("keyword") >= 0 && $(this).attr("href").toLowerCase().indexOf("keyword2") >= 0 && $(this).attr("href").toLowerCase().indexOf("keyword3") >= 0) || ($(this).attr("href").toLowerCase().indexOf("keyword4") >= 0)) {
                _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'eventCategories', 'eventAction', 'eventLabel']);
            if (this.target != '_blank') delayLink(e, this.href);
            }
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response will give the delay a try and get back to you tomorrow :D. Thanks